# How to set FedAuth cookie SessionToken.IsPersistent conditionally when SessionSecurityTokenCreated

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies, wif, ws-federation

I am using WIF with WS Federation so that my ASP.NET application can authenticate against an STS (Thinktecture IdentityServer).  In my RP I would like to pragmatically set the cookie persistence based off of the claims of the user.

Watching the traffic in Fiddler I can see the WIF FedAuth cookie is first set when the STS token is posted to the RP.  Before the cookie is set I would like to intercept some event and either set the cookie to be persistent (or not) depending on the current claims.

I understand that I can set the cookie persistence in the web.config, however this behavior needs to be conditional based off of the user.

```
<wsFederation ... persistentCookiesOnPassiveRedirects="true" />
```

My first approach was to try handling the various SessionSecurityTokenCreated events but these events never seemed to be fired.  **Am I adding the handlers incorrectly?  Or is there a better way of doing this?**

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...

    FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SessionSecurityTokenCreated +=
        new EventHandler<SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs>(SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated);

    FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule.SessionSecurityTokenCreated +=
        new EventHandler<SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs>(WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated);

}



//This never seems to fire...
void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated(object sender,
        SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal.HasClaim("someClaim", "someValue"))
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = true;
    else
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = false;
}


//This never seems to fire either...
void WSFederationAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated(object sender,
        SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal.HasClaim("someClaim", "someValue"))
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = true;
    else
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = false;            

}
```

Interesting to note:  if I add a handler for SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived this event seems to fire.  Here I can re-issue the cookie and set *IsPersistent = true* but this doesn't get fired until after the cookie is first set and I would prefer to do this when the cookie is first issued.

After testing a bit:  If I Reissue the cookie in SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived then SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated will be fired.  I just can't seem to find out why this is not fired on the initial creation of the cookie when the token is first POSTed to the RP.

Comment: It appears that the WSFederationAuthenticationModule events were not being fired because I was assigned a custom class deriving from WSFederationAuthenticationModule in the web.config.  I don't know why the custom WSFederationAuthenticationModule isn't firing off the events (or executing my handlers added in the App_startup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source of my problem was:
  a)  I was using a custom WSFederationAuthenticationModule.
  b)  I wasn't wiring up the events in the Global.asax using the name of the custom module.

Assuming my web.config has this in it:

```
<system.webServer>

// ...

    <add name="MyCustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule"
     type="MyLib.MyCustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule, Thinktecture.IdentityModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"
     preCondition="managedHandler" />

    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule"
     type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
     preCondition="managedHandler"  />


// ...

</system.webServer>
```

And assuming "MyCustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule" is the name of the custom fed-auth module.  Then I just had to fix the name of the method handler (with nothing in app start).

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    //Nothing here.
}

//This never seems to fire either...
void MyCustomWSFederationAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenCreated(object sender,
        SessionSecurityTokenCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal.HasClaim("someClaim", "someValue"))
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = true;
    else
        e.SessionToken.IsPersistent = false;            
}
```